# Не корректный вывод массива из файл .txt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

У меня есть код, который сохраняет, а потом достает из файла .txt массив, после чего загружает его в таблицу, но при выводе таблице получаю вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый символ поместился в отдельную ячейку в первом столбце, как это исправить? Результат должен выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Запись в файл:**

```
directory_save_hotel = os.getcwd() + "/SaveDateHotel" + "/save_hotel.txt"
        with open(directory_save_hotel, 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(data))
```

**Вывод из файла:**

```
directory_save_hotel = os.getcwd() + "/SaveDateHotel" + "/save_hotel.txt"
        with open(directory_save_hotel, 'r') as file:
            data = file.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

**В файле:**

```
[['No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data'], ['No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data'], ['No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data'], ['No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data', 'No data']]
```

Comment: Вы переводите данные в текст перед записью в файл. Но вы не переводите текст обратно в данные после прочтения его из файла. [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: Уберите, пожалуйста, весь код и картинки из вопроса кроме двух строк записи и двух строк чтения.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете чуть по подробнее про перевод?

Comment: Так как вы работате с табличными данными, посмотрите на Pandas. Он хранит, обрабатывает, записывает и читает таблицы из коробки. Куда лучше рукописных решений.

Comment: Я удовольствием отвечу на ваш вопрос во всех подробностях если вы уменьшите его объём в десять раз: пример данных, процедура записи, процедура чтения, пример результата, собственно вопрос. Извините, но я поклонник искусства задавания вопросов.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я уменьшил объём вопроса, оставил только запись и вывод из файла. Пример из файла тоже оставил.

Comment: Спасибо. Режим записи `'a'` добавляет данные в файл. Старые данные из файла не стираются. Вы действительно этого хотели?

Comment: `data = file.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')` -> `data = ast.literal_eval(file.read())`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy только сейчас заметил, нет данные должны перезаписывается, это если я не ошибаюсь режим  W?

Comment: Да, это `'w'` .

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy PyCharm ругается на ast

Comment: `import ast` вы сделали?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy сделал, проблема была в PyCharm, перезапустили и ошибка ушла, все работает как надо. Оформите ваш комментарий как ответ и я приму  его.

Comment: Спасибо, но нет, не буду. И вопрос и ответ не несут большой пользы для остальных. Был рад помочь.